Proxy_pass not working with Nginx with https to http with extra sub route item
I have a domain, for example:
https://www.example.com/
We have a custom made website and is running in the root of the application. Now in the next phase, we would like to add Wordpress site as route of the main site. This for better SEO.
I want to have it on a different WordPress hosting site, which is dedicated for WordPress and does not conflict with our main site.
We have a nginx server installed, which function as a gateway for all our domains. This works just fine with location in combination with proxy_pass.
But now I cannot seem to get something working. For example, I want a WordPress website on:
https://www.example.com/site1
This is being hosted on a different hosting party, but is reachable by:
http://12.34.56.78/~abcdef/site1/
I tried multipe setups with proxy_pass, but I am unable to get it working. So I have basically 2 questions:

Is this even possible with Nginx?
And if so, can you maybe tell me how, as I am unable to get working?

Hope you can help me!
